# SQL show ONLY displayed duplicates after filtering out duplicates with same results in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(code), connection, standing 
FROM data
WHERE code IN (SELECT code 
               FROM data 
               GROUP BY code 
               HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
ORDER BY code
```

The problem I have is that it shows all duplicates.

Basically I wanted to show duplicates if they have different values in either connection or standing but It also shows duplicates (in only 1 row because of the DISTINCT) that have same value in either connection or stand.

What I have and want:

```
Code   Connection  Standing
----------------------------
XXX    YYY         YYY
XXX    ZZZ         YYY
```

But I also have:

```
Code   Connection  Standing
---------------------------
WWW    YYY         YYY
```

And that code is there only once because of the distinct.

So can I filter out single results after the distinct?

Not sure if its understandable but I hope so.

EDIT: To add more sample of what my problem is:

```
Code   Connection  Standing
---------------------------
XXX    YYY         YYY
XXX    ZZZ         YYY
YYY    SSS         YYY
YYY    SSS         ZZZ
TTT    SSS         YYY
```

I want to get rid of `TTT` line because its not really the duplicate I am looking for. I want to see duplicates that have different values in either connection or standing.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,c`. It always applies to all columns in the select list.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies on the whole selected rows. To avoid confusion, remove those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT code , connection, standing FROM data...`.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I need to see duplicates in column Code that have different values in either Connection or Standing and I need to filter out if in Code there is single result (that is duplicate but have same results in Connection or Standing so it hides because of DISTINCT) and these single results after filtering I need to hide.

Comment: Is is oracle or sqlserver?

Comment: From the above query what you are getting the result.

Comment: Its sqlserver. Or can I write it differently to get the duplicates with different results in Connection or Standing

Comment: With above query are you getting result as 2 records which are having same code,but 2 different connections and standing

Comment: Yes, I am looking for 2 or more of the same records that have different connections and standing and want to filter out the single result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are three major steps involved in what you are looking for:

1. Get the distincts combinations of Code, Connection and Standing
2. Get all the values of Code which exist more than once in the resul from 1.
3. Get all the rows from the result from 1. whose Code exist in the result from 2.

One way from achieving this is with the help of [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Connection,Standing FROM @T)

SELECT CTE.Code,Connection, Standing FROM CTE INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Code FROM CTE GROUP BY Code HAVING COUNT(*) >1) AS tCode ON tCode.Code = CTE.Code
```

Another way may be using CTEs and [Window Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Connection,Standing FROM @T),
CTE2 as (
SELECT CTE.Code,Connection, Standing, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code) as CodeCount 
FROM CTE) 
SELECT Code, Connection, Standing FROM CTE2 WHERE CodeCount > 1
```

This last option may prove more powerful depending on what you want to do. For example, if you would like to know how many times a Connection value or Standing value exist in relation to a certain Code value:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Connection,Standing FROM @T),
CTE2 as (
SELECT CTE.Code,Connection, Standing, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code) as CodeCount, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Connection)
as ConnectionByCodeCount, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Standing)
as StandingByCodeCount 
FROM CTE) 
SELECT Code, Connection, ConnectionByCodeCount, Standing, StandingByCodeCount FROM CTE2 WHERE CodeCount > 1
```

Would return:

```
Code| Connection| ConnectionByCodeCount  | Standing| StandingByCodeCount
----| ----------| -----------------------| --------| -------------------
XXX | YYY       | 1                      | YYY     | 2 (times YYY, Code XXX)
XXX | ZZZ       | 1                      | YYY     | 2
YYY | SSS       | 2 (times SSS, Code YYY)| YYY     | 1
YYY | SSS       | 2                      | ZZZ     | 1
```